# How to validate whether date selected or not in datetimepicker control in C#?

Tags: c#

I am checking whether datetimepicker value selected or not with datetimepicker current system running date.

I am getting error as Cannot implicitly convert System.DateTime to bool
How to fix this?

```
else if (dtpDOB.Value = DateTime.Today)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Select DateOfBirth");
}
```

Comment: use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: no the `==` not working. MessageBox not displaying.

Comment: your error resolved by using `==`.

Comment: values are not as same as each other so _MessageBox not displaying._

Comment: no @HamedMoghadasi its not effecting to my code. I want to check whether datetimepicker date value changed or not. If datetimepicker value not selected i want to show error message as "Select DateOfBirth"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to like this, remember that the value needs to be a date that is coming from the DateTimePicker.

```
if(empRegBdatePicker.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    //birthdate is today
}
```